# How do you convert a single element of a double array to a QString?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

My code is this:

```
void Tests::writeResultsFile(QString &logTestResults, QString 
&combinedResultsS, double &combinedResultsN, QString &deviceId)
{
    QFile file(logTestResults); //open test results file

    QString convertedNumbersResults[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
     //below line doesn't work as is
     convertedNumbersResults[i] = QString::number(combinedResultsN[i],'f',2);         
    }

    file.remove();                                                            
    }
file.close();
}
```

when I compile I receive this error: "C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type"

Comment: In which line says that the error is generated, also if you want us to help you, you must provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: this line `convertedNumbersResults[i] = QString::number(combinedResultsN[i],'f',2); `

Comment: double &combinedResultsN????? What is that? Use QStringList, this is not C, it is C ++, where arrays of that type are not used.

Comment: See this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html, double &combinedResultsN Has no sense

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the extremely useful and descriptive comments, it never occurred to me to look at the documentation, that's super helpful and not something I have seen on here before.  Also very helpful to post 4 separate comments stating the same insightful information, kudos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out the issue, as @eyllanesc so eloquently and politely pointed out, I was passing my array incorrectly.

The correct way:

```
void Tests::writeResultsFile(QString &logTestResults, QString 
combinedResultsS[2], double combinedResultsN[12], QString &deviceId)
{
QFile file(logTestResults); //open test results file

QString convertedNumbersResults[12];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
       //below line works now
       convertedNumbersResults[i] = QString::number(combinedResultsN[i],'f',2);         
     }

    file.remove();                                                            
   }
file.close();
}
```